# Strange JSON keyerror python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

I have been getting some strange key errors when trying to load a value after a few game ticks in my case, there is no modification going on cause most of it gets loaded from class internally at initiation, here is an quick example of the error im getting when trying to access.
also link to source is [here](https://github.com/boedaka/RPG_engine_python), im pretty new and just have been coding for aint to long so please no judgement.

```
{'calleas': {'player': {'x': 5, 'y': 5, 'id': 'npc_1'}, '1': {'x': 6, 'y': 8, 'id': 'npc_2'}, '2': {'x': 5, 'y': 8, 'id': 'npc_3'}}, 'calleas_forest': {'player': {'x': 55, 'y': 5, 'id': 'npc_1'}}}
{'calleas': {'0': {'object_id': 7, 'x': 0, 'y': 5, 'walkable': True, 'gamestate': 'callaes_forest'}, '1': {'object_id': 7, 'x': 0, 'y': 4, 'walkable': True, 'gamestate': 'callaes_forest'}}, 'callaes_forest': {'0': {'object_id': 7, 'x': 56, 'y': 5, 'walkable': True, 'gamestate': 'callaes_forest'}, '1': {'object_id': 7, 'x': 56, 'y': 4, 'walkable': True, 'gamestate': 'callaes_forest'}}}
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jannick/PycharmProjects/NewRemake/Game.py", line 39, in <module>
    g.start_game()
  File "C:/Users/Jannick/PycharmProjects/NewRemake/Game.py", line 33, in start_game
    self.update()
  File "C:\Users\Jannick\PycharmProjects\NewRemake\GameHandler.py", line 106, in update
    self.entity_handler.update()
  File "C:\Users\Jannick\PycharmProjects\NewRemake\Entity\EntityHandler.py", line 21, in update
    self.game.player.update()
  File "C:\Users\Jannick\PycharmProjects\NewRemake\Entity\Entity.py", line 35, in update
    self.move(x=1)
  File "C:\Users\Jannick\PycharmProjects\NewRemake\Entity\Player.py", line 47, in move
    self.game.map_handler.load(self.game.map_handler.new_map_name(dest_x, dest_y))
  File "C:\Users\Jannick\PycharmProjects\NewRemake\World\MapBuilder.py", line 26, in load
    self.get_map_configuration(map_config)
  File "C:\Users\Jannick\PycharmProjects\NewRemake\World\MapBuilder.py", line 46, in get_map_configuration
    "entitys": self.all_map_entitys[map_config]
KeyError: 'callaes_forest'
{'calleas': {'player': {'x': 5, 'y': 5, 'id': 'npc_1'}, '1': {'x': 6, 'y': 8, 'id': 'npc_2'}, '2': {'x': 5, 'y': 8, 'id': 'npc_3'}}, 'calleas_forest': {'player': {'x': 55, 'y': 5, 'id': 'npc_1'}}}
```

Comment: Are calleas_forest and callaes_forest intentionally named different?

Comment: Ah lol thanks i think its time to sleep.

Comment: Haha.. Good Night